# How can I enable VPN only for a specific app?

Tags: root-access, security, vpn

I want a spesific app to be only connected through a VPN all the time, while everything else remains normal and not connected through VPN. How can I achieve this?

Moto C Plus | Android 7 | Rooted.

Comment: The app you are using to create VPN must have [per-app VPN](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn#per-app) feature enabled. Or with root privileges you can try to manipulate the routing table manually. Android makes use of UIDs and `SOcket MARKs` to filter apps from VPN.

Comment: I use Afwall+ with Orbot (per app VPN supported). In Orbot I enabled VPN access to my app of choice (XYZ app). In AFwall+, I enabled VPN interface along with wifi and mobile data. In whitelist/allowlist mode in AFwall+, I allowed my XYZ app to only use VPN. As a result, my XYZ app can only access internet when OrBot is running and is providing VPN service. Otherwise, it gets no internet access. Other apps works fine without VPN.

Comment: @Firelord Hi, can you show your screenshot for AFwall+? How to make app only use VPN?

Comment: @KellinStrook Hi. I no longer use AFWall+. It became unstable on my Android 10 after a while and I could not fix the problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

ProtonVPN has a split tunneling function  and destination access/non-access.

Comment: The windows version have this feature. The android version does not. You can include an app but you can't single-out an app to be routed thru ProtonVPN.