# Route some traffic via VPN while the rest routed as usual (non-VPN)

Tags: networking, vpn, android-12, google-pixel-3-xl

I manage some servers where VPN is the only access for maintenance. On Linux, we use xl2tpd, strongswan-starter, and ip-route. I want to gain access to my phone (Pixel 3, Android 12) such that traffic for the servers routes via the VPN, and all else remains routed as usual, not via the VPN.

How may this be done on Android 12?

Comment: [How to exclude a specific destination IP from VPN?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/241910/218526). With small changes you can make it like "How to route a specific destination IP through VPN?". Requires root.

Comment: See also https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236859/how-can-i-enable-vpn-only-for-a-specific-app

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a lot of detail for understanding your situation thoroughly, but perhaps take a look at split tunneling. I use ProtonVPN's Split Tunneling function for this purpose. Excluding IP-addresses thus does NOT require root, except when having to use ip-tables.
https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/howtos/forwarding.html